# Update one value in Oracle database based on a condition with RJDBC

Tags: oracle, rjdbc

I am trying to update a value in an Oracle database connected using RJDBC (the connectionis fine as I can query the database from within R).
I tried the following (and many variants of it):

```
dbSendUpdate(db_iot, "UPDATE IOT_DATA SET IOTFILE = (?)  WHERE VARIABLE = (?);", "1_prod_vorl_0.Rmd", 'wss')
```

In Oracle Developer I can run the query like this without any problems:

```
UPDATE IOT_DATA SET IOTFILE = '1_prod_vorl_0.Rmd' WHERE VARIABLE = 'wss';
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Renger

Comment: Try removing parentheses in parameter placeholders. And also remove semicolon.

Comment: library(RJDBC)
dbSendUpdate(db_iot, "UPDATE IOT_DATA SET IOTFILE = ? WHERE VARIABLE = ?", "1_prod_vorl_0.Rmd", 'wss')

Didn't work. R is hanging and nothing seems to happen. I have to kill RStudio and restart. 

If I add the semicolon, I get the following message

Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  execute JDBC update query failed in dbSendUpdate (ORA-00933: SQL-Befehl wurde nicht korrekt beendet

Comment: Try executing the statement without using placeholders:
`dbSendUpdate(db_iot, "UPDATE IOT_DATA SET IOTFILE = '1_prod_vorl_0.Rmd'  WHERE VARIABLE = 'wss'")`

And you could try using `dbSendStatement` instead

Comment: dbSendUpdate(db_iot, "UPDATE IOT_DATA SET IOTFILE=? WHERE VARIABLE=?", "11_prod_vorl_0.Rmd", 'wss')  worked. Thanks!